# Beginner Error, Incompatible types

Tags: android, view, textview, widget

Now I begin to learn android programming. Example of an older book I found in it. Here's the problem location.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mytextview = findViewById(R.id.textView);
    pluszgomb = findViewById(R.id.button);
    minuszgomb = findViewById(R.id.button2);
    mytextview.setText("A számláló értéke: "+ szamlalo);
    pluszgomb.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

        }
    });
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });
}
```

At line 5 the Android Studio provides that:

Incompatible type.

Required : android.widget.View

Found : android.view.View

Where 's the problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Check your imports. If you see

`import android.view.View;`

You will need to change it to:

`import android.widget.View;`

Or if you are using a `android.view.View` you will need to add a cast to `android.widget.View` like so

```
widget.View widgetView = (widget.View) view;
```

Answer (score 1):

check your imports if there was a :

```
import android.view.View
```

then change it to :

```
import android.widget.View
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to typecast it to (TextView)

```
TextView tv ; 
tv =  (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
```